# Azure Functions and ASP.NET Web API: Do net treat missing values as empty strings

Tags: c#, azure, function, deserialization, webapi

This seems to apply to both, azure functions and ASP.NET Core Web API: Assume that you have a simple class:

```
SomeClass
{
   propA: string;
   propB: string;
}
```

In the Controller you add something like this

```
... [FromBody]SomeClass data
```

The runtime will now instantiate a object named data with the json values provided in the body.

However, if you provide this json:

```
{
   "propA": "SomeText"
}
```

it will still instantiate propB with an empty string, although no value is present in the body. Now the question would be: Is it possible to suppress that behavior, so not to set propB if there is no value provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your string properties with the `[Required]` data annotation.

```
[Required]
public string A { get; set; }
```

This does however enable empty strings like:

```
{
   "propA": ""
}
```

The data annotation `[Required]` has an extra property: `AllowEmptyStrings`. If set to false the above property will not validate.
Do take in mind these validation annotations cause `400` statuscodes in your responses.

Comment: Yes, but propB should not be required. That is the deal. So if it is not provided in the body-json of the request, simply do not set it - and not assign empty strings to it.

Comment: @ITfromBit Ah, is [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) what you are looking for then?

Comment: I apologize. It was the constructor of the class that did the unwanted assignments, not ASP.NET Core. Nevertheless: The required-Attribute was a very useful tip. Thank you!